# Adding height values to map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, grass-gis, layers, 3d

I am facing a couple of issues - I think they are related.

Firstly...
I am attempting to add height values to my habitat survey map to produce a 3D map in QGIS 3.12.3. I have height values stored in the attribute table of my 'Habitats [EPSG:4326]' layer. I have attempted **'v.to.3d, v.extrude, v.drape'**. I have Grass downloaded.

When I run my Habitat layer through '**v.to.3d**' this is the response:

```
QGIS version: 3.12.3-București
QGIS code revision: 8234261527
Qt version: 5.11.2
GDAL version: 3.0.4
GEOS version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'v.to.3d' starting…
Input parameters:
{ '-r' : False, '-t' : False, 'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001, 'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' : -1, 'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO' : '', 'GRASS_VECTOR_EXPORT_NOCAT' : False, 'GRASS_VECTOR_LCO' : '', 'column' : 'Height', 'height' : None, 'input' : 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/LakeProject/Habitats.shp', 'output' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'type' : [0,1,2,3] }

g.proj -c proj4="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="C:\Users\user\Desktop\LakeProject\Habitats.shp" output="vector_6064c1b33c0b88" --overwrite -o
g.region n=37.78757493408765 s=37.786860653618696 e=-122.46628277404538 w=-122.46736208177902
v.to.3d input=vector_6064c1b33c0b88 type="point,line,boundary,centroid" column=Height output=output44f423749e334146bd0b61f2bd3c9837 --overwrite
v.out.ogr type="auto" input="output44f423749e334146bd0b61f2bd3c9837" output="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_avIvGR\036287ea21bc449d8ac1e2a6646b5a83\output.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
The system cannot find the file C:\rtools40\Version.txt.
Starting GRASS GIS...
WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
Cleaning up temporary files...
Executing <C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_avIvGR\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> ...
C:\Users\user\Documents>chcp 1252 1>NUL
C:\Users\user\Documents>g.proj -c proj4="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default
Projection information updated
C:\Users\user\Documents>v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="C:\Users\user\Desktop\LakeProject\Habitats.shp" output="vector_6064c1b33c0b88" --overwrite -o
Over-riding projection check
Check if OGR layer <Habitats> contains polygons...
0..3..5..7..9..12..14..16..18..20..23..25..27..29..32..34..36..38..40..43..45..47..49..52..54..56..58..60..63..65..67..69..72..74..76..78..80..83..85..87..89..92..94..96..98..100
Creating attribute table for layer <Habitats>...
Column name <Common nam> renamed to <Common_nam>
Column name <Species na> renamed to <Species_na>
Column name <Native?> renamed to <Native_>
Importing 55 features (OGR layer <Habitats>)...
0..3..5..7..9..12..14..16..18..20..23..25..27..29..32..34..36..38..40..43..45..47..49..52..54..56..58..60..63..65..67..69..72..74..76..78..80..83..85..87..89..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Registering primitives...
-----------------------------------------------------
Cleaning polygons
-----------------------------------------------------
Breaking polygons...
Breaking polygons (pass 1: select break points)...
1..3..5..7..10..12..14..17..19..21..24..26..28..31..33..35..38..40..42..45..47..49..52..54..56..59..61..63..66..68..70..73..75..77..80..82..84..87..89..91..94..96..98..100
Breaking polygons (pass 2: break at selected points)...
1..3..5..7..10..12..14..17..19..21..24..26..28..31..33..35..38..40..42..45..47..49..52..54..56..59..61..63..66..68..70..73..75..77..80..82..84..87..89..91..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing duplicates...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Breaking boundaries...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing duplicates...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Cleaning boundaries at nodes...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Breaking boundaries...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing duplicates...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Cleaning boundaries at nodes...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Merging boundaries...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing dangles...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Building areas...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..-----------------------------------------------------
Removing bridges...
38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Registering primitives...
Building areas...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
Attaching islands...
0..25..50..75..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Finding centroids for OGR layer <Habitats>...
0..3..7..10..14..18..21..25..29..32..36..40..43..47..50..54..58..61..65..69..72..76..80..83..87..90..94..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Writing centroids...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
56 input polygons
Total area: 3101.68 (100 areas)
Overlapping area: 5.079 (28 areas)
Area without category: 0.487711 (15 areas)
-----------------------------------------------------
Copying features...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
Building topology for vector map <vector_6064c1b33c0b88@PERMANENT>...
Registering primitives...
Building areas...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
Attaching islands...
0..25..50..75..100
Attaching centroids...
0..2..4..7..9..11..14..16..18..20..22..24..27..29..31..34..36..38..40..42..44..47..49..51..54..56..58..60..62..64..67..69..71..74..76..78..80..82..84..87..89..91..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
28 areas represent multiple (overlapping) features, because polygons overlap in input layer(s). Such areas are linked to more than 1 row in attribute table. The number of features for those areas is stored as category in layer 2
-----------------------------------------------------
If overlapping is not desired, the input data can be cleaned by snapping vertices to each other.
Estimated range of snapping threshold: [1e-013, 0.0001]
C:\Users\user\Documents>g.region n=37.78757493408765 s=37.786860653618696 e=-122.46628277404538 w=-122.46736208177902
C:\Users\user\Documents>v.to.3d input=vector_6064c1b33c0b88 type="point,line,boundary,centroid" column=Height output=output44f423749e334146bd0b61f2bd3c9837 --overwrite
Fetching height from <Height> column...
Transforming features...
Copying attributes...
Building topology for vector map <output44f423749e334146bd0b61f2bd3c9837@PERMANENT>...
Registering primitives...
WARNING: Number of centroids exceeds number of areas: 85 > 0
WARNING: Number of centroids outside area: 85
Vertical extent of vector map <output44f423749e334146bd0b61f2bd3c9837>: B: 1.000000 T: 200.000000
C:\Users\user\Documents>v.out.ogr type="auto" input="output44f423749e334146bd0b61f2bd3c9837" output="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_avIvGR\036287ea21bc449d8ac1e2a6646b5a83\output.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
WARNING: Unable to determine input map's vector feature type(s).
WARNING: 85 centroids found, but not requested to be exported. Verify 'type' parameter.
WARNING: Vector map <output44f423749e334146bd0b61f2bd3c9837> is 3D. Use format specific layer creation options (parameter 'lco') to export <in 3D rather than 2D (default).
WARNING: Output layer is empty, no features written
v.out.ogr complete. 0 features (Unknown (any) type) written to <output44f423749e334146bd0b61f2bd3c9837> (GPKG format).
C:\Users\user\Documents>exit
Execution of <C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_avIvGR\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> finished.
Cleaning up default sqlite database ...
Cleaning up temporary files...
ERROR: Variable 'LOCATION_NAME' not set
Execution completed in 7.55 seconds
Results:
{'output': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'v.to.3d' finished
```

I then used '**setzvalue**' and ran this through '**v.to.3d**'. This is the response:

```
QGIS code revision: 8234261527
Qt version: 5.11.2
GDAL version: 3.0.4
GEOS version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'v.to.3d' starting…
Input parameters:
{ '-r' : False, '-t' : False, 'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001, 'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None, 'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' : -1, 'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO' : '', 'GRASS_VECTOR_EXPORT_NOCAT' : False, 'GRASS_VECTOR_LCO' : '', 'column' : 'Height', 'height' : None, 'input' : 'MultiPolygonZ?crs=EPSG:4326&field=Common%20nam:string(80,0)&field=Type:string(80,0)&field=Family:string(80,0)&field=Species%20na:string(80,0)&field=Native%3F:string(80,0)&field=Count:integer(9,0)&field=area:double(10,3)&field=Height:integer(9,0)&uid={b1fe6523-b273-4151-a591-eab708491441}', 'output' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'type' : [0,1,2,3] }

g.proj -c proj4="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_avIvGR\9f7b0bb10dfa41caa5e1af9b3b58d710\input.shp" output="vector_6064c16a802c47" --overwrite -o
g.region n=37.78757493408765 s=37.786860653618696 e=-122.46628277404538 w=-122.46736208177902
v.to.3d input=vector_6064c16a802c47 type="point,line,boundary,centroid" column=Height output=outputb2265b6f9e1246a3a2a4af54327fd670 --overwrite
v.out.ogr type="auto" input="outputb2265b6f9e1246a3a2a4af54327fd670" output="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_avIvGR\35a2a43d3c87434ba77218f43b130b9c\output.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
The system cannot find the file C:\rtools40\Version.txt.
Starting GRASS GIS...
WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
Cleaning up temporary files...
Executing <C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_avIvGR\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> ...
C:\Users\user\Documents>chcp 1252 1>NUL
C:\Users\user\Documents>g.proj -c proj4="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the default
Projection information updated
C:\Users\user\Documents>v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_avIvGR\9f7b0bb10dfa41caa5e1af9b3b58d710\input.shp" output="vector_6064c16a802c47" --overwrite -o
Over-riding projection check
Check if OGR layer <input> contains polygons...
0..3..5..7..9..12..14..16..18..20..23..25..27..29..32..34..36..38..40..43..45..47..49..52..54..56..58..60..63..65..67..69..72..74..76..78..80..83..85..87..89..92..94..96..98..100
Creating attribute table for layer <input>...
Column name <Common nam> renamed to <Common_nam>
Column name <Species na> renamed to <Species_na>
Column name <Native?> renamed to <Native_>
Importing 55 features (OGR layer <input>)...
0..3..5..7..9..12..14..16..18..20..23..25..27..29..32..34..36..38..40..43..45..47..49..52..54..56..58..60..63..65..67..69..72..74..76..78..80..83..85..87..89..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Registering primitives...
-----------------------------------------------------
Cleaning polygons
-----------------------------------------------------
Breaking polygons...
Breaking polygons (pass 1: select break points)...
1..3..5..7..10..12..14..17..19..21..24..26..28..31..33..35..38..40..42..45..47..49..52..54..56..59..61..63..66..68..70..73..75..77..80..82..84..87..89..91..94..96..98..100
Breaking polygons (pass 2: break at selected points)...
1..3..5..7..10..12..14..17..19..21..24..26..28..31..33..35..38..40..42..45..47..49..52..54..56..59..61..63..66..68..70..73..75..77..80..82..84..87..89..91..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing duplicates...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Breaking boundaries...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing duplicates...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Cleaning boundaries at nodes...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Breaking boundaries...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing duplicates...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Cleaning boundaries at nodes...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Breaking boundaries...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing duplicates...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Cleaning boundaries at nodes...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Merging boundaries...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing dangles...
1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Building areas...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..WARNING: Number of incorrect boundaries: 117
-----------------------------------------------------
Removing bridges...
50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Registering primitives...
Building areas...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
WARNING: Number of incorrect boundaries: 415
-----------------------------------------------------
Finding centroids for OGR layer <input>...
0..3..7..10..14..18..21..25..29..32..36..40..43..47..50..54..58..61..65..69..72..76..80..83..87..90..94..98..100
-----------------------------------------------------
Writing centroids...
33..66..100
-----------------------------------------------------
56 input polygons
Total area: 55.1933 (3 areas)
Area without category: 0.0278723 (1 areas)
-----------------------------------------------------
Copying features...
2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100
Building topology for vector map <vector_6064c16a802c47@PERMANENT>...
Registering primitives...
Building areas...
0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
Attaching islands...
0..25..50..75..100
Attaching centroids...
0..50..100
WARNING: Number of incorrect boundaries: 117
-----------------------------------------------------
WARNING: The output contains topological errors:
Number of incorrect boundaries: 117
The input could be cleaned by snapping vertices to each other.
Estimated range of snapping threshold: [1e-013, 0.0001]
Try to import again, snapping with 1e-009: 'snap=1e-009'
C:\Users\user\Documents>g.region n=37.78757493408765 s=37.786860653618696 e=-122.46628277404538 w=-122.46736208177902
C:\Users\user\Documents>v.to.3d input=vector_6064c16a802c47 type="point,line,boundary,centroid" column=Height output=outputb2265b6f9e1246a3a2a4af54327fd670 --overwrite
ERROR: Vector map <vector_6064c16a802c47> is 3D
C:\Users\user\Documents>v.out.ogr type="auto" input="outputb2265b6f9e1246a3a2a4af54327fd670" output="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_avIvGR\35a2a43d3c87434ba77218f43b130b9c\output.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
ERROR: Vector map <outputb2265b6f9e1246a3a2a4af54327fd670> not found
C:\Users\user\Documents>exit
Execution of <C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_avIvGR\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd> finished.
Cleaning up default sqlite database ...
Cleaning up temporary files...
Press any key to continue . . .
Execution completed in 7.08 seconds
Results:
{'output': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_avIvGR/35a2a43d3c87434ba77218f43b130b9c/output.gpkg</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

They have very different responses.

Second...
Most of my layers have a projection of: EPSG 4326/WGS 84. However, my Bing base map is EPSG 3857/ WGS 84. When I have tried to change my Bing base map to EPSG 4326/WGS 84, my layers disappear from the screen - which makes sense.

Is there an issue with my projection which is why I am unable to produce a 3D map?

Comment: "it does not work" is not very helpful. What happens when you run the tool? Which error do you get? Have you tried using data in a different CRS?

Comment: @Erik I have edited my post to contain the response and result. I have tried changing the CRS, I set all the layers and project to a different CRS and it could not be drawn onto QGIS. Do I need to transform the projection?

Answer (score 2):

In response to your comment, "setting" the projection is almost always the **wrong** thing to do. If you need to use a different projection then in nearly all cases (I'd say 99.9% of the time :-) ) you must do a transform.

But before addressing the coordinate system, I think your problem is with the original habitats shapefile. In the output message that you posted (thanks for that) there is a warning and suggestion:

```
WARNING: The output contains topological errors:
Unable to calculate a centroid for 1 areas
The input could be cleaned by snapping vertices to each other.
Estimated range of snapping threshold: [1e-013, 0.0001]
Try to import again, snapping with 1e-009: 'snap=1e-009'
```

It seems that the Habitats polygons are not topologically clean: there might be overlaps, overshoots, polygons that are not closed, or other issues. Try adding the snap parameter (perhaps with an even bigger threshold, 1e-6 or similar) and report back if that improves the result.

And, as a second approach, there's a QGIS tool in Processing: `SetZValue`. That might also work for you. You can use the Expression builder to choose your Height column as the Z value.

Comment: Hey Micha, thanks for this! I have managed to isolate the polygon that had an invalid geometry and fixed that part. I then used SetZValues and now have a Z value and ran this through 3.to.3d, I also tried running the original habitat layer through 3.to.3d with the fixed geometry, neither worked... I will edit my post to add the responses. Thanks for helping me troubleshoot this! Appreciate it

Comment: You'll probably want to start a new question, since the issue is different now.

Comment: Okay, I will do this. Thanks Micha (: